# Getting error "readchar is not defined" when trying to read one character from user

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to accept only one character from user. I searched on the internet and I found `readchar`. It's fine while using this in my terminal. I get my expected answer. But when I want to write a program using this it throws an error:

```
     File "recon.py", line 142, in <module>
    z=repr(readchar.readchar())
NameError: name 'readchar' is not defined
```

Refer to this image to better understand:

[image]

This is my code:

```
try:    
    if os.getuid()!=0:
        print banner
        print 'print'
        print 'Do you want to Continue (y/n:'
        z=repr(readchar.readchar())
        z=z.replace("'",' ').replace('"',' ')
        z=z.lower()
        if z=='n':
            print "it's always a good idea to get full output"
            exit()
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared at the top(anywhere) of your code file  `import readchar` ?

This can happen because of 3 reasons:

1. `readchar` not installed, which seems from console is installed.
2. `pip` packages not found by interpreter. Which is again can be seen available on your console.
3. You have not declared the import statement.